# JSF commandLink onclick not working, but commandButton is?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsf

I am working with JSF and have implemented a JS function that is called when commandLinks and Buttons are clicked on. The function is used to prevent multiple submissions if the link/button is clicked on more than once. The problem is that it works on all buttons and some links, even though it is always called when being clicked on :S This is the JS function:

```
var formSubmitted = false;
function onSubmit() { 
    if (!formSubmitted) {
        formSubmitted = true;
    } else {        
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a working button:

```
<h:commandButton onclick="onSubmit()" value="#{Buttons.andraVGU}" rendered="#{vardgivareVGBean.visaAndraVgu}"
action="#{vardgivareVGBean.actionAndraVGU}" />
```

And here is an example of a link that calles the function but still gives me an exception.

```
<h:commandLink value=""
  onclick="onSubmit()"
  action="#{forslagTillaggBulkBean.oppnaFastTillagg}"
  onmouseover="onMouseOverTableRow(this); return false"
  onmouseout="onMouseOutTableRow(this); return false"
  disabled="#{forslagTillagg.tillaggTypAsString=='TILL'}">
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{forslagTillagg.uppdrag}"
  styleClass="#{forslagTillagg.status != 'N' ? 'farg' : 'greyedout'}" />
    <f:param name="fastTillaggID"
    value="#{forslagTillagg.fastTillaggID}" />
  <f:param name="fastTillaggGiltigt"
    value="#{forslagTillagg.tillaggTypGiltig}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Here is a commandLink that works:

```
<h:commandLink onclick="onSubmit()" value=""
  actionListener="#{oversiktBean.valjFakturaRad}"
  onmouseover="onMouseOverTableRow(this); return false"
  onmouseout="onMouseOutTableRow(this); return false">
```

I realise that one difference between the links are that the ones that does not work have nested tags, but I don't see why that would cause an issue.

I would really appreciate an explanation from you experienced guys!
Thanks!

Comment: If you get an exception then please add it to the question.

Comment: Indeed. A good exception is already the whole answer to your problem. It's just a matter of being able to read it. If you can't then you should definitely include it in your question so that we can translate it in layman's terms for you so you finally understand the answer provided to you. That is where this question is all about, right?

Comment: @sinclair and BalusC I am getting a javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 590,00". When I googled it, the answers I got was that there is some problem casting but it works when I click once, the issue only occurs because of double submission.

Comment: @BalusC help please :)?